# Should the question "What to read in History of Middle-earth?" have been closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question in question: [What to read in History of Middle-earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247659/what-to-read-in-history-of-middle-earth)

It's had a little bit of history to it, originally closed as a dupe to: [In what order should Tolkien's writings on Middle-earth be read?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15534/in-what-order-should-tolkiens-writings-on-middle-earth-be-read) where I was one of the close voters. However, after further discussion in the comments I think this one is sufficiently different to that and it was reopened.

It has later been closed as "Opinion based". However, [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) questions, which this is, generally do not fall under "Opinion based" and are the type of good subjective questions we allow.

Having already voted to reopen it the first time around I now can't do so again and probably shouldn't to stop a close/reopen war.

Should this question have been closed?

Comment: It shouldn't have been closed as opinion based at the very least

Comment: @fez - It's a dupe of a wider question. I'm at a loss why it's been re-opened and then (more bizarrely) closed again.

Comment: I'm not interested in getting into a close war, so I'm fine with it staying open. If the question were about the suggested order for Silmarillion, Children of Hurin, Beren and Luthian, Hobbit, LotR, then sure, I'd see it as a suggested-order question. However, since it was about "The History of Middle-Earth" collected work, which, to my mind, is much like LOTR in that it's a single volume of multiple 'books' - it's like asking if there is a suggested reading order for the chapters withing LOTR itself. So, that's what was in my brain when vtc

Answer (score 6):

The question could've been worded better, to avoid the trappings of opinion-basedness, but I agree that it should be on topic, as [suggested-order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-order) questions are in general.